How to close questions that are not useful to others
In particular, this is in regard to Infrared sensor behavior. The problem was user error. It's not likely that this question would be of use to anyone else and may in fact come up in searches where someone has a problem with the infrared sensor, but of course this won't help them. None of the options under close seem to match though. What are other moderators doing in cases like this?
For reference, here are the options:

duplicate of... This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
off-topic because... This question does not appear to be about LEGO Bricks within the scope defined in the help center.
unclear what you're asking Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
too broad There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.
primarily opinion-based Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.


Originally these would probably have been closed as "Too Localised", however that was removed a couple of years ago and the recommendation now is to use "Off Topic", and then probably select "Other - add a reason".
That said, there might be some value in having your comment that points out that the Infra-red and Ultrasonic sensors can be easily confused turned into an answer for future readers ;)
